# Apache 2.4 Event MPM - Unable to override MaxRequestWorker and ThreadsPerChild default configuration

Tags: events, apache2.4

We are using Apache 2.4 and we are trying to configure the MaxRequestWorker and ThreadLimit for Event MPM. Below is the configuration I have in apache's httpd.conf. But the configuration doesn't seem to take any effect. It still continues to use default values of (400 MaxRequestWorker and 25 Threads). Not sure if I am missing anything in my configuration.

I want to configure my server to use 1024 MaxRequestWorker and 64 ThreadsPerChild.

We have roughly 2Gig RAM and 2Gig in SWAP, Apache 2.4 (EVENT MPM) and Red Hat Linux OS.

Any help would really help. Thank you so much!!

```
Httpd.conf
------------
    Event MPM
    # StartServers: initial number of server processes to start
    # MaxClients: maximum number of simultaneous client connections
    # MinSpareThreads: minimum number of Event threads which are kept spare
    # MaxSpareThreads: maximum number of Event threads which are kept spare
    # ThreadsPerChild: constant number of Event threads in each server process
    # MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
    <IfModule event.c>
    ServerLimit   16
    StartServers      8
    MaxRequestWorkers 1024
    MinSpareThreads   75
    MaxSpareThreads   250 
    ThreadsPerChild   64
    ThreadLimit   64
    MaxConnectionsPerChild 0
    </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realise that this is an old post. Just in case anyone else comes across this again.

1. Check the *exact* module name. If you check /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf (or equivalent location, this was on RHEL 7/CentOS 7) for the line that loads the events module:

LoadModule mpm_event_module

2. Copy this module name 'mpm_event_module'.
3. Rather than specifying this at the end of httpd.conf, it's better practice to create a file in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ called mpm_event.conf and load it there.

In this instance, I believe changing:

```
<IfModule event.c>
```

to

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
```

3. Then restarting HTTPD, would have fixed it.

Kind Regards,

Will